# Kinesis - handling write ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We are using AWS Kinesis as a persistent queue. Kinesis has max 1000 writes/s, 1M/s in total per shard limit.  80% of our use case fall below the limit. However, there are some spikes exceeding the total 1M/s. It is not cost-effective to reserve more writing capacity for these spikes.

Any suggestions?

1. Let the SDK handle ProvisionedThroughputExceededException retry?
2. write events to a temporary place and flush once reaching 1M?
3. ...?

Comment: What AWS SDK are you using? Java? Python? JS?

Comment: I m using Nodejs sdk

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the awslabs project for [kinesis autoscaling](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-scaling-utils).

This will automatically increase the number of shards during the peak times, and reduce it during less activity. You can configure the thresholds via a Autoscaling policy to do that.